# URL not found after setting asp-controller and asp-action attributes

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have no idea why my asp-controller don't want to show my pages.
I have a controller named UserTemplatesController and this method there :

```
public ActionResult ADfind()
{
    return View();
}
```

the view attached to this method is called ADfind, so in my Razor page
I tried to add this into another card like that :

```
<li><a asp-controller="UserTemplatesController" action="ADfind">ADfind</a></li>
<li><a asp-controller="UserTemplatesController" action="Index">Usermgr</a></li>
(...)
```

but everything what I see when I want to load this page is :

```
http://localhost:9505/UserTemplatesController
HTTP ERROR 404
```

Anyone have some idea to solve this ?

Comment: Because it needs to be `asp-controller="UserTemplates"` (not `"UserTemplatesController"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a naming convention of ASP.NET MVC that controllers must be named controller at the end. The ASP.NET routing module adds Controller to the given name and searches for a class with this name. In your case your class should either be named `UserTemplatesControllerController` or your action should look like this:

```
<li><a asp-controller="UserTemplates" asp-action="ADfind">ADfind</a></li>
<li><a asp-controller="UserTemplates" asp-action="Index">Usermgr</a></li>
```

Furthermore the attribute for the action is called `asp-action`.

Comment: Shouldn't it also be asp-action=?

Comment: @Silvermind of course you are right, I just copy pasted.